# Traverse only those elements which are divisible by the current element in an array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, c++14, binary-tree

Consider an array: `10 2 4 14 1 7`
Traversing the input array for each valid i, I have to find all the elements which are divisible by the i-th element. So, first I have to find all the elements which are greater than the i-th element.

Example output:

```
10 -> null
2 -> 10
4 -> 10
14 -> null
1 -> 14,4,2,10
7 -> 14,10
```

My approach:
I was thinking of creating a binary tree that would perform a log n  operation for each valid insertion in an array that would re-construct the binary tree with the minimum element as root, smaller element on the left and greater element on the right. Now I just have to traverse the right sub-tree of the inserted element and check which elements are divisible by the i-th element. This is a very expensive approach but better than brute-force.

Can anyone help to find an optimal solution that would be more efficient?

Comment: Your question is a little ambiguous.  Is the function supposed to take an array as input and then return a list of lists like `[None, [10], [10], None, [14,4,2,10], [14,10]]`.  Or does it take the array and an index and return a list of elements > array[i]?

Comment: no, I wrote that because it would be easy to understand. The actual output should be a single integer which is the maximum number of elements that the i-th element would divide.

Comment: So calling the function would look like `function(array, index)` and it would return the number of values at indexes 0...(i-1) that are divisible by the value at index `i`?  Do you expect to call the function several times with the same array but different indexes?

Comment: Yes, but the complete approach should be O(nlogn) and not O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

**Worst-case time complexity can be no better than O(n^2). Hence the brute force solution is just fine.**

Consider the below input (which is also a worst-case):

```
arr = [1, 1, 1,  ..., 1, 1]
```

For `arr[0] = 1`, in the answer, there will be `0 elements`.

For `arr[1] = 1`, in the answer, there will be `1 element`.

...

For `arr[n - 2] = 1`, in the answer, there will be `n - 2 elements`.

For `arr[n - 1] = 1`, in the answer, there will be `n - 1 elements`.

So, the total no of elements in the answer will be:

```
0 + 1 + 2 + ... + (n - 1)
= ((n - 1) * n) / 2
= O(n^2)
```

**If you just want to find `the number of elements and not the actual elements`, then yes better solutions exist.**

Comment: Sir, I have edited the question to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

### built a list of decreasing runs

As the list is scanned, if the current element is <= the element at the end of the last run, add it to the run.  It not, start a new run with the current element.

The example array becomes `[[10, 2], [4], [14, 1], [7]]`.

It is then a simple matter of scanning each run and doing something with the elements that are larger than element[i].

Here is example code that processes the input array, and returns a list of lists.

```
def bigger_so_far(seq):
    results = []
    runs = []

    for element in seq:
        if runs:
            if element > runs[-1][-1]:
                runs.append([])
            runs[-1].append(element)

        else:
            runs.append([element])

        result = []
        for run in runs:
            for j in run:
                if j <= element:
                    break
                result.append(j)

        results.append(result)

    print(runs)

    return results
```

Sample run:

```
bigger_so_far([10, 2, 4, 14, 1, 7]) #=> [[], [10], [10], [], [10, 2, 4, 14], [10, 14]]
```